# Can't redirect all requests with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to hide the real URL on my website, so what I have is:

```
mydomain.com/customers/[customer_name]
```

Redirects to

```
mydomain.com/scripts/get_customer_page.php?customer=[customer_name]
```

The redirection is working, but all the files CSS/JS files required by `get_customer_page.php` aren't working.

The browser looks at:

```
mydomain.com/customers/[customer_name]/css
```

This is what my .htaccess file looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^customers/(.*)/?$ scripts/get_customer_page.php?customer=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Use the absolute path for your css, js and images on your HTML code instead of relative path. So instead of using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/my.css">` you use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mydomain.com/css/my.css">`. When using relative path it assumes that the closest folder is the root and that's why you get that and in your case `customers/[customer_name]` is considered as folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solve this problem by editing the .htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# When there is not only one "/" i.e. mydomain.com/customers/path_to_some_file
RewriteRule ^customers/(.*/.*)/?$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^customers/(.*)/?$ scripts/get_customer_page.php?customer=$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your links to absolute URLs or add a relative URI base to the header of your page:

```
<base href="/customers/" />
```